# unit test for static global variable viz. _paq

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, matomo

I am using matomo (previously piwik) for my website analytics with my angular7 application.

As per the documentation, I paste the tracking code to my index.html file of my application. The content looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
/* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
(function() {
  var u="//example.com/";
  _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
  _paq.push(['setSiteId', '43']);
  var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})();
```

So, this helps to load matomo.js static file from example.com/matomo.js url. This exposes global variable _paq.

Now I want to use this global variable in my matomo.service.ts file to track the events. Since _paq is not a angular variable, I explicitely declare it in matomo.service.ts file something like this:

```
declare let _paq: any[][];
```

Now I can create different methods in this service file to push analytics data to the server.

## matomo.service.ts

```
...
declare let _paq: any[][];
...

trackEvents(category,action, label) {
  _paq.push(['trackEvent', category,action, label];
}
```

This works well from any component, example

## app.component.ts

```
constructor(private matomoService: MatomoService) {}
trackEvent(category, action, label) {
    this.matomoService.trackEvents(category, action, label);
}
```

Everything works very well till here. But when I try to run unit test, it fails all components which calls this method (this.matomoService.trackEvents(...) with error:

***ReferenceError: _paq is not defined***

I tried different methods suggested in other similar questions but none work.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: Are you using the *actual* `MatomoService` in your unit tests? Why not replace it with a test double? `declare let _paq: any[][];` is just a type declaration saying "this will definitely exist at runtime", it doesn't do anything to actually make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I can create dummy service but the problem is then I need to create this dummy matomoService in all of the components that I want to avoid. cc @jonrsharpe

Comment: You can extract that to a shared file if you want to, but it only needs to be something like `createSpyObj('MatomoService', ['trackEvents'])` (see https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpyObj%3C/code%3E). That's one of the points of extracting collaborators like services, to decouple *to make testing easier*.